# Setting date fields to number of days away closest to a specific time

Tags: sql

How do I write an sql script which helps me correct the date to specific number of days away which is closest to a specific time.The field type is Date

For example (+ 5 days away at 2pm)

**Before**

```
Record 1: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 4-Nov-20 3pm    
Record 2: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 10-Nov-20 4am    
Record 3: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 12-Nov-20 2pm    
Record 4: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 21-Oct-20 3.50pm
```

**After**

```
Record 1: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 10-Nov-20 2pm (Adjusted to next day as it missed the 2pm timing)    
Record 2: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 15-Nov-20 2pm    
Record 3: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 17-Nov-20 2pm   
Record 4: Date_Of_Creation(Date): 27-Oct-20 2pm
```

This only adds specific number of days

```
Update table
    set Date_Of_Creation = DATEADD(day, 5, Date_Of_Creation)
```

Note that there are many records,so no hard coded method preferred.

Comment: perhaps state the role-over amount, try to make a sample so they know what you are after, just edit your question

Comment: Hi - please tag your question with the DB that you are using. Also, just to be clear, is your logic: add 5 days to the column and then move to the next occurring 2pm?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a time to a `datetime` value.  So add five dates, remove the time, convert back to a `datetime` and add the time:

```
Update table
    set Date_Of_Creation = convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(day, 5, Date_Of_Creation))) + '14:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming SQL Server here since you mention DATEADD, so something like this (taking one of your values above as representative)?

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT CAST('4-Nov-20 3pm' AS DATETIME) AS myTime
) SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(
                  hour, 
                  (5 * 24) 
                  + 14 - DATEPART(hour, myTime), myTime), 
                  'd-MMM-yy htt') as newTime
FROM t1
```

P.S. If you need the `PM` to be lowercase, one way would be to wrap the `FORMAT` with a `REPLACE(FORMAT..., 'PM', 'pm')`